# How to install application built from flutter in linux

Tags: c++, linux, flutter, native

So I have built a linux app in flutter and now I want to create a native application for linux. I have run `flutter build linux` in my ***WSL environment*** and after few efforts, it has successfully built the application.

My problem is that in the `/build/linux/x64/release` directory there is a bunch of files (which supposedly are the build files):

```
CMakeCache.txt  build.ninja  cmake_install.cmake    flutter               intermediates_do_not_run
CMakeFiles      bundle       compile_commands.json  install_manifest.txt  plugins
```

now I have copied this file to a Linux environment. But I have no idea how to compile/build/run the application. What do I do with these files?

Comment: Refer this for better understanding of how to build and release Linux App: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/linux